# Need to validate code inputted by user which include letters and numbers

Tags: java, validation

Basically I want the user to enter a code in this format  - XXXX000 and if the user enters 3 letters and 4 digits for example - it outputs an error.

What i did is that i wrote a command that input has to be maximum 7 characters but it doesn't specify what the characters need to be. Therefore if user enters 7 digits, it is still accepted which it should not.

```
System.out.print("Enter the animal's unique code - Format: (XXXX111)");
       String codein = in.nextLine();
       a.setCode(codein);

          if (codein.length() != 7) {
              System.out.println("Format was not met, please try again");
              System.out.println("Enter the animal's unique code - Format: (XXXX111)");
              codein = in.nextLine();
              a.setCode(codein);
        }
```

An error should appear if user does not enter in this format XXXX000

Comment: You can match it with a regular expression using [String.matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-)

Comment: try to match it with a regex pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `X` means A-Z and a-z and `0` means 0-9 in your pattern, you can use this pattern to valid the code:

```
[A-Za-z]{4}\d{3}
```

For more info on regexes, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Use it like this:

```
if (codeine.matches("[A-Za-z]{4}\\d{3}")) {
    // valid
} else {
    // invalid
}
```